# Python Import problems for installed module

Tags: python, import, pip

I've spent 2 hours trying everything to get this python module working. It's a security module called Kitty Fuzzer.

I've installed it "pip install kittyfuzzer" as well as tried "pip2 install kittyfuzzer". It shows as installed when doing python -c "import kitty".

However when I run a script that imports a submodule (like the script below), it says that submodule is not found. I've checked the source and API, and it's definately there (e.g. https://github.com/cisco-sas/kitty/blob/master/kitty/fuzzers/client.py).

Any tips for getting the import to work?

I've tried running it in python2 and python3

Test script:
https://github.com/cisco-sas/kitty/blob/master/examples/01_file_generator/runner.py

thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Kittyfuzzer is supporting only Python 2. 
You can validate this by open kittyfuzzer's setup.py:

```
# python 3 - install only the remote package
if sys.version_info >= (3,):
setup(
    name='kittyfuzzer-remote',
    ...
# python 2 - install full kitty framework
else:
    setup(
    name='kittyfuzzer',
    ...
```

I suppose you installed it for Python 3 only. 
What you should to do is to run following command "pip install kittyfuzzer" directly from folder with Python 2 pip installer(for example: C:\Python2\Scripts). This will install kittyfuzzer for Python 2. Now you can run your code with Python 2.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your help, I didn't know to look in setup.py to find out the version.